# Why wont these two scenarios return the same output?

Tags: python

Hello bellow there are two runs of the same function. They should both return `AB` as the answer. But only the first one does. What is going on with the global variables?

```
txt=''

def test():
    global txt
    txt+='A'
    print(txt)
    return 'B'
tmp=test()
print('tmp: ', tmp)
txt+=tmp
print(txt)
```

**Second Run**

```
txt=''

def test():
    global txt
    txt+='A'
    print(txt)
    return 'B'
print(txt)
txt+=test()
print(txt)
```

**EDIT**

[image: proof]

Comment: My guess is that when you execute the function in "Second Run" python stores a reference to what the string was at that very point. When the value is returned and txt += adds 'B' the 'A' simply is gone.

Comment: Did you really do `txt = ''` before the second run?

Comment: @Barmar i add photografic proof.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In second example

```
txt += test()
```

this could be broke down to

```
txt = txt + test()
```

In this case, the first `txt` doesn't be change to `A`.

Therefore, you are actually doing

```
txt = '' + 'B'
```

For the first example, the `txt` variable has already been change to `A` in the process of `tmp` are created.

Therefore, for the

```
txt += test()
```

You are doing `txt = 'A' + 'B'`

Comment: Yep, this is what I had in mind aswell. But this was easier to understand +1.